# What might cause Vanilla Forums permission changes after an update?

Tags: php, vanilla-forums

I've updated our Vanilla Forums from 2.1.10 to 2.2, and now I get a "Sorry, permission denied" message if I try to log in (as admin). If I register as a new user, I don't have the issue at all.

I've worked through the trouble shooting guide, with no luck, and I came across this seemingly [related thread](http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/13673/error-when-members-try-to-sign-in-sorry-permission-denied). Still, I don't understand what would cause this error. Is it something in the config.php file or something in the database that needs to be updated?

### Additional Information

- I've tried the default forum skin.
- I've tried disabling all the plugins.
- I've found that the config.php file seems to have the old info (because the version number is wrong).
- The PHP version is fine.
- I couldn't find the gdn_permission table in the database. What creates this? Can I build and populate it myself?
- When I disabled the Yaga application, I was able to log in.

Comment: In the end, the problem was Yaga. I don't know why this caused the problem though, so my question remains. The following [tutorial](http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/31153/tutorial-a-fool-proof-way-to-do-a-vanilla-upgrade-from-2-1-to-2-2) is very helpful for anyone doing the update.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the 2.2 upgrade changes the way passwords are stored. Perhaps the issue is related to how existing passwords are now being stored?

It's worth checking - did you run `/utility/update` when upgrading? If not, that might explain the issue.

Comment: I did run '/utility/update' a number of times. 

Anyone know why Garden.SignIn.Allow in permissions is often refered to in the help for this issue?